# How to retrieve a VarBinary document to an ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL Server database that I am using ASP.NET MVC to upload documents and images (PDF's txt ect..).

I have 2 questions:

1. I have the datatype for the image column currently as `varbinary(MAX)`, but is there a better datatype to use (image)?
2. How in ASP.NET MVC do I create an `ActionLink` to open these files? Or even just download them?

I am not sure I am going about this correctly since the image could be any extension. Here is some controller code I have been testing with:

```
public byte[] GetImageFromDataBase(int Id)
{
     var q = from temp in db.Swap where temp.ID == Id select temp.Image;
     byte[] cover = q.First();
     return cover;
}
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)   - so using `VARBINARY(MAX)` is actually the **preferred** option - you should **AVOID** `IMAGE` at all costs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Accodring to [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) and [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) you should prefer using `varbinary(max)`

2) Create an action which returns a file

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult DownloadFile(int id)
    {
        byte[] fileContent = GetImageFromDataBase(id);
        string extension = //get image extension;

        return File(fileContent, "image/" + extension, "filename from db");
    }
}
```

Then in a view create a link to this action

```
@Html.ActionLink("Get image", "DownloadFile", "Home", new { id = 5}, null)
```